# Turn on error messages for my website

Tags: php, apache, cpanel

I have a website which I am managing via cpanel. However there are some errors I am trying to fix on this site. The problem I am facing is that when the code hits an error, there is no error message showing, it simply shows a blank page. How do I get to see these error messages?

Comment: See the manual, http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php; or the wiki here, http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info

Answer (score 0):

You can set PHP error reporting on in php.ini file (in case you have access to this file). Set the following lines:

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL
display_errors = On
```

Comment: any idea on how i can access php.ini via cpanel

Comment: check this https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Edit+Your+php.ini+File

Comment: That' not work on server with Apache+PHP mod... 500 error.